# How to Customize the Toggle Switch in UWP

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, styles, uwp

I am developing a UWP windows 10 app. In that I have a search toggle. I want to change the toggle color and height. How can I do this.?
Thanks In advance..

Comment: You could do it editing the control template.

Comment: how can I write? Can u give any example?

Answer (score 2):

You have to open Blend and create an empty project. Drag and drop the desired control into the designer, right click on it and select "Edit a copy". Switch your view to XAML then you will be able to see the default style of your control. Thus you can modify the initial control template and make it look like whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Control template for customization of the toggle switch and got it.